# Are drivers for android things compatible with the regular Android OS?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, driver, android-things, odroid

so my original goal was to install an external GPS module to a single board computer running android and be able to run navigation apps using the GPS data from the GPS module. I first tried using a raspberry pi 3 running android things. I bought a GPS hat for it and found this appropriate driver

https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps

However, after installing android things I decided that it wasn't exactly what I was expecting and wanted a full-fledged version of android along with access to the google play store. I am currently debating buying a Odroid single board computer and installing Android on it, not android things. My question is, would the driver above work with Android and my GPS module? The Odroid I am looking at has the same 40 pin layout as the pi so the GPS hat should connect properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drivers use the Android thing peripheral IO library, which is not available on standard Android.
So, in short: No.